# getting error System.InvalidOperationException: The object type 'cms.document' is missing the provider type configuration Kentico 13 API

Tags: kentico

When i create  new page type in kentico 13 getting below error

System.InvalidOperationException: The object type 'cms.document' is missing the provider type configuration.

Comment: You may want to provide more information about your error.  Where are you receiving this error?  What hot fix are you on?  Are you using MVC5 or .NET core?  Details help solve the problem.

Comment: Have you checked this thread too? https://devnet.kentico.com/questions/error-cms-document-is-missing-the-provider-type-configuration